# Filename string comparison in list search fails [Python]

Tags: python

I am trying to associate some filepaths from 2 `list` elements in Python. These files have a part of their name identical, while the extension and some extra words are different.

This means the extension of the file, extra characters and their location can differ. The files are in different folders, hence their filepath name differs. What is exactly equal: their Numbering index: `0033`, `0061` for example.

**Example code:**

```
 original_files = ['C:/0001.jpg',
     'C:/0033.jpg',
     'C:/0061.jpg',
     'C:/0080.jpg',
     'C:/0204.jpg',
     'C:/0241.jpg']

 related_files = ['C:/0001_PM.png',
     'C:/0033_PMA.png',
     'C:/0033_NM.png',
     'C:/0061_PMLTS.png',
     'C:/0080_PM.png',
     'C:/0080_RS.png',
     'C:/0204_PM.png']

 for idx, filename in enumerate(original_files):    
      related_filename = [s for s in (related_files) if filename.rsplit('/',1)[1][:-4] in s]    
      print(related_filename)
```

At `filename = 'C:/0241.jpg'` it should return `[]`, but instead it returns all the filenames from `related_files.`

For privacy reasons I didn't post the entire filepath, just the names of the files. In this example, the comparison works, but for **the entire filepath it fails**.

I suppose my comparison condition is not correct but I don't know how to write it.

Note: I am looking for something with as few code lines as possible to do this.

Comment: 'while the extension and some extra words are different' We need more information here. What exactly will be equal, what can differ?

Comment: @LutzHorn my bad. the extension of the file and their location can differ. The files are in different folders, hence their filepath name differs. What is exactly equal: their Numbering index: `0033` for example.

Comment: Am I correct that the name of each file starts with some numbers, followed by a `_`? Are these numbers the unique identifier that con be used find the related file?

Comment: @LutzHorn You are almost right. Each original file name can also be a combination of letters and numbers. These names are unique identifier. The related files contain an unique identifier from `original_files` followed by `_`  and some other words. So, in the `related_files` the unique identifier from the `original_files` can appear multiple times. I updated my example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something along the line of

```
from collections import defaultdict

original_files = ['C:/0001.jpg',
    'C:/0033.jpg',
    'C:/0061.jpg',
    'C:/0080.jpg',
    'C:/0204.jpg',
    'C:/0241.jpg']

related_files = ['C:/0001_PM.png',
    'C:/0033_PMA.png',
    'C:/0033_NM.png',
    'C:/0061_PMLTS.png',
    'C:/0080_PM.png',
    'C:/0080_RS.png',
    'C:/0204_PM.png']

def key1(filename):
    return filename.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].rsplit('.', 1)[0]

def key2(filename):
    return key1(filename).split('_', 1)[0]

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in related_files:
    d[key2(x)].append(x)

for x in original_files:
    related = d.get(key1(x), [])
    print(x, '->', related)
```

In `key1()` and `key2()` you could alternately use `os.path` functions or `pathlib.Path` methods.

Comment: this answer assumes that I have only `2 characters` after the `_` in `relative_files` but that is not the case. The number of `characters` after the `_` is variable. I update my example code.

Comment: This is good, BUT how do I make `related = d.get(key1(x), None)` to retrieve **all** related file names. For example, for `x=C:\0033.jpg` I want to have `related = [ 'C:/0033_PMA.png', 'C:/0033_NM.png']`.

Comment: All right, new update, now using a defaultdict for d :)

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.X you can try to use this:

```
for origfiles in original_files:
    for relfiles in related_files:
        if origfiles[3:6] == relfiles[3:6]:
            print(origfiles)
```

Comment: This is not correct. The names don't only differ in the extension.

Comment: @Lutz Horn yeah I just read the new edit that he now specifies what really needs to be matched. I'll edit my answer a bit but the structure would still remain.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of defaultdict.

```
import os, re
from collections import defaultdict

stragglers = []
grouped_files = defaultdict(list)
file_index = re.compile('([0-9]+)')

for f in original_files + related_files:
    m = file_index.match(os.path.split(f)[1])
    if m:
        grouped_files[m.group(1)].append(f)
    else:
        stragglers.append(f)
```

You now have `grouped_files`, a dict (or dictionary-like object) of key-value pairs where the key is the regex matched part of the filename and the value is a list of matching filenames.

```
for x in grouped_files.items():
    print(x)
# ('0204', ['C:/0204.jpg', 'C:/0204_PM.png'])
# ('0001', ['C:/0001.jpg', 'C:/0001_PM.png'])
# ('0033', ['C:/0033.jpg', 'C:/0033_PM.png'])
# ('0061', ['C:/0061.jpg', 'C:/0061_PM.png'])
# ('0241', ['C:/0241.jpg'])
# ('0080', ['C:/0080.jpg', 'C:/0080_PM.png'])
```

In `stragglers` you have any filenames that didn't match your regex.

```
print(stragglers)
# []
```

Comment: @Roxanne Here is a solution, it will also work on varying folders.

Comment: I would really like a solution that directly returns **only** the matched `relative_files` for each `element` from `original_files`. If the `original_file` element doesn't have any associated `relative_file` then I don't want to append it to the final list.

Comment: @Roxanne Could do `[x[1] for x in grouped_files.values() if len(x) > 1]` from here. There's a better way though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that returns only the matched relative_files.

```
import os, re

def get_index(filename):
    m = re.match('([0-9]+)', os.path.split(filename)[1])
    return m.group(1) if m else False

indexes = filter(bool, map(get_index, original_files))
[f for f in related_files if get_index(f) in indexes]
```